# function is_file() always returns false

Tags: php

i had started PHP programming some days before. and I'm was writing a script to upload a file on the server.  After the server verifies the image was correct type (png, gif or jpeg), the user was to be given an confirmation message. i used is_file() and getsize() for this, but these functions always returned false. Once, Linux gave me an warning that selinux policy was denying access to httpd to access the image data. permissions to the image and its containing folder are set to 0777. 
please help me.
thanx in advance ..

Comment: Can you show us the specific code you're using? Also, the vowels on your keyboard seem to be stuck. ;)

Comment: Sometimes the root path for php is different to the URL path - you need to add in the root before the dir path.

Comment: you can't solve your problem nor get an aswer here without an **error message**.

Comment: Set the error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors", 1); and: do you use move_uploaded_files() function?

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to `open_basedir` restrictions.

If this option is set and the file you're trying to access is not under one of the paths specified, it's not accessible to `is_file()`.

Comment: thank u all for ur answers. i got my solution. i had set my upload directory to /images/, then removing the first slash and setting path to images/, solved my problem. this was the first time, i tried to get a solution for my problem this way; and i'm pleased to know this method's efficiency. thanx again ....